# React. Why is the return inside a map, not the other way around?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and reading this code: https://github.com/john-smilga/react-advanced-2020/blob/master/src/tutorial/4-forms/final/1-controlled-inputs.js (long...)

What I don't understand is this part (line 53-61):

```
    {people.map((person, index) => {
      const { id, firstName, email } = person;
      return (
        <div className='item' key={id}>
          <h4>{firstName}</h4>
          <p>{email}</p>
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

Why is the **return** inside a **map** ?  Since the map is taking items from the array and operating on them individually, won't there be multiple returns for each operation ?

Thank very much !

Comment: array.map method returns a new array

Comment: The parameter to ```map()``` is a callback function. In this case ```(person, index) => {...}``` Each element in your array will be passed as a person to this function, and you are returning an html representation. You get a new array of the mapped person

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal Yes, agree.  But shouldn't the map then just be dedicated to producing the array ?  Won't the return disrupt the creation of the new array ?  And won't it create multiple returns ?  That's what I don't understand.

Comment: @sintribu oh... I understand now.  I got confused by the return, thinking that's the return for the overall javascript.  That return is at line 27.  Thanks !!!

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal  I got confused by the return, thinking that's the return for the overall javascript. That return is at line 27. Thanks !!!

Comment: actually, it will return an array of JSX items here , that array will show it's item on the screen

Comment: @Data T - I think you understand, but the ```map``` itself returns the array, the function passed to map returns the new element. I posted an answer to demonstate.

Comment: each time you return from the callback function it stores in the array

Comment: @DataT I have mentioned modified version of your code, this the recommended way you don't need to destructure  item properties.

Comment: @sintribu Yes, I understand how the call back function works.  I'm new to React and Javascript, so I got confused by the codes.  I was watching the video and the screen didn't show the whole piece of code, so I thought it's the React return.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const l = [1, 2, 3]

const mapped_array = l.map(li => {
    console.log(li) // 1, 2, 3
    return 10 * li  
})

console.log(mapped_array)
/// [10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to destructure person properties, you can also use the other way-**

```js
{people.map((person, index) => 
(
        <div className='item' key={person.id}>
          <h4>{person.firstName}</h4>
          <p>{person.email}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about [Array#map in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#description).

> map calls a provided callbackFn function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results.

So the function that is called for each array element must return something. That return value is then used to construct the new array.

Comment: I got confused by the return, thinking that's the return for the overall javascript. That return is at line 27. Thanks !!!

Comment: @DataT I see your confusion. There are 3 return keywords in this file: the one on line 19 is for `handleSubmit` function, line 27 is for `ControlledInputs` component, and line 55 is for the `map` callback

Comment: Yes, I was struggling with the way Javascript and React works and didn't realise that this return is the call back function of the map.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax:

```
() => { /* ... */ }
```

creates a function. The `return` statement inside of it only returns that small function that was passed to the `map()` function, but doesn't return from the outer function.

Comment: I got confused by the return, thinking that's the return for the overall javascript. That return is at line 27. Thanks !!!